# How to open multiple xslx files in Python with the same columns from the xlsx

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I did some adjustments I got the code to work here However the columns headings ended up being in a row and where the column headings should be I got numbers for column headings instead like 1, 2, 3.... I would like to get the column names from the xlsx files. Here is the code:

```
# import modules
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 999)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',100)
%matplotlib inline

# filenames
file_names = ["data/OrderReport.xlsx", "data/OrderReport2.xlsx"]

# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in file_names]

# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]

# concatenate them
atlantic_data = pd.concat(frames)

# write it out
combined.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: What's the issue? Just iterate and import with `pd.read_excel`.

Answer (score 0):

I have attached below link of full documentation

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

I would simply suggest you that xlsx file format is not always the best choice for work on pandas. What I always prefer is to get data read in dataframes and then export in .csv format for further analysis/works.

Comment: Ok I made some adjustments to the code. I got a merged dataframe which is called atlantic_data but im having an issue with the column names. Appreciate the help ! @Harry_pb